# Loop through a list of ranges with continuous indexes

Tags: python

I have written the code below which does what I want but I was wondering if there a way to optimize it for large data , I will eventually be getting the ranges from a file.

```
l=[2,6,4,9]
p=0
index=0
j=0
for i,s in enumerate (l):
    p=p+s
    for j in range(index,p):
        print(j)
    index=j+1
    print('-------------')
0
1
-------------
2
3
4
5
6
7
-------------
8
9
10
11
-------------
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
-------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use one loop

```
k = 0
i = 1
for j in range(sum(l)):
  print(j)
  if (i == l[k]):
    i -= l[k]
    k += 1
    print('-------------')
  i += 1
```

Comment: I will be performing different processes on each range , so I can't simply add the items in the array.

Comment: Then, please, formulate your question more precisely. People here did not get what you want so far.

Comment: managed to change my logic to make it work with the solution above , thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good solution, using numpy:

```
import numpy as np

l=[2,6,4,9]
arr = list(np.cumsum(l))

for i in range(arr[-1]):
  if i in arr:
    print('-------')
  print(i)
print('-------')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor change:

```
for i,s in enumerate (l):
    p += s
    for j in range(index,p):
        print(j)
    index = p # j+1 == p here
```

Answer (score 0):

You could build a list of lists using accumulate.  This would make it easier to manipulate the result in the rest of your program.

```
chunks=[2,6,4,9]

from itertools import accumulate
ix = [ [*range(end-size,end)] for size,end in zip(chunks,accumulate(chunks)) ]

print(ix)

# [[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]]
```

If you're only looking for a printing loop, then accumulate can also help:

```
breaks = set(accumulate(l))
for i in range(sum(l)):
    if i in breaks: print("---------")
    print(i)
```